# What we can infer from there exists x satisfying P

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

If it is known that there exists x satisfying P, can we infer that there also exists x not satisfying P?

I ask this question since I have a problem as follows.

Given three premises:
(1)if a student likes math, he doesn't like social studies.
(2)every student likes math or social studies.
(3)some students like math.

can we come to a conclusion that there exists student who doesn't like math?

Comment: Of course not. What if $P=\top$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO.

Assume a domain with only the number $0$. We have that $P(x) := (x=0)$ is satisfied while $\lnot (x=0)$ is not.

We say that we can *infer* or *deduce* $\psi$ from $\varphi$ when $\psi$ is a *logical consequence* of $\varphi$; in symbol : $\varphi \vDash \psi$.

It can be useful to go back to the source of *formal logic* : [Aristotle](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-logic/) for the notion of *valid* argument, i.e. of an argument that is "justified by virtue of form alone".

In Aristotle's logic :

> > A *deduction* is speech (*logos*) in which, certain things having been supposed, something different from those supposed **results of necessity because of their being so** [emphasis added]. (*Prior Analytics* I.2, 24b18-20)
>
> The core of this definition is the notion of “resulting of necessity” . This corresponds to a modern notion of logical consequence: **X** results of necessity from **Y** and **Z** if it would be impossible for **X** to be false when **Y** and **Z** are true. We could therefore take this to be a general definition of “valid argument”.
>
> Aristotle proves invalidity by constructing counterexamples. This is very much in the spirit of modern logical theory: all that it takes to show that a certain form is invalid is a single instance of that form with true premises and a false conclusion. However, Aristotle states his results not by saying that certain premise-conclusion combinations are invalid but by saying that certain premise pairs do not “syllogize”: that is, that, given the pair in question, examples can be constructed in which premises of that form are true and a conclusion of any of the four possible forms is false.

Thus, my counterexample above shows that :

> $P(x) \nvDash \lnot P(x)$

i.e. from the fact that there exists $x$ satisfying $P$, we **cannot** infer (or deduce) that there also exists $x$ not satisfying $P$ (i.e. satisfying $\lnot P$).

Comment: What if the domain is students in one school. There are some students who love math. Can we infer that there are some students who do not love math?

Comment: **NO** : see my expanded answer. Of course, the fact that we **cannot** infer it (i.e. the argument is **not** valid) does not mean that there can be no students who do not love math...

Comment: Thank you very much for your very clear explanation. It is now clear for me that the answer is no. Now since I already add my problem that derives my question. Can you give a comment on it?

Comment: @IlhamRizkianto - in the case described in the expanded question, the answer is : NO. From (3) we have a Student $a$ such that : $LoveMath(a)$. From (1) : $LoveMath(a) \rightarrow \lnot LoveSocSt(a)$. Thus, by *modus ponens* : $\lnot LoveSocSt(a)$ and so we have that there exists at least one student that does not like Social Studies. But from this we cannot use (1) or (2) to conclude that he does not love Math (in fact, we started from the fact that it loved Math ...).